# Get value with key of object in an array (javascript)

Tags: javascript

How can I get the value for an object in an array if I know it's key?

```
const array1 = [
  {a: ['A1','A2']},
  {b: ['B1','B2']},
  {c: ['C1','C2']},
]
```

For example, I'd like to print the value for the object with the 'a' key value which would equal:

```
['A1','A2']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a variation on @junvar's answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/66443048/

```
const array1 = [
  {a: ['A1','A2']},
  {b: ['B1','B2']},
  {c: ['C1','C2']},
];

let key1="a";

console.log(matchKey(array1, key1));  // [ 'A1', 'A2' ]

function matchKey(array, key) {
 
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    let {[key]: value} = array[i];
    if (value) return value;

  }

}
```

### Can you change to an Object?

It seems a lot simpler based on the sample data you provided to make it an object and then simply return the values you want based on the property name.

example:

```
const object1 = {
   a: ['A1','A2'],
   b: ['B1','B2'],
   c: ['C1','C2']
};

console.log(object1.a); // [ 'A1', 'A2' ]
```